# Slow loading KML file on Leaflet...can I load portion of it?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a simple map using ESRI leaflet and omnivore to load a 34MB KML file. It takes about 1 minute to load. Is there a way to load it based on the bounds of the map? I need to access some of the attributes of each polygon onclick, so this will probably limit some of my options in terms of converting KML to image, etc. To get the KML file I'm working with, I converted a shapefile into KML via Google Earth.

I noted this option in the documentation: 
.kml.parse(kmlString | gpxDom): Parse KML from a string of XML or XML DOM, and return layer. Is there a way to pre-parse the KML based on some lat/lon filters...or based on the map bounds...and then display a smaller portion of the KML? Or do I need to convert the KML to something else more flexible to display?

Here's how I'm loading the KML file.

```
var glacier_np_layer = omnivore.kml('counties.kml', null, L.geoJson(null, {style: countystyle }));
glacier_np_layer.addTo(map1);
```

Here's a link: http://blueandthegreen.com/ltg/county.html and http://blueandthegreen.com/ltg/counties.kml
Sorry for no jsfiddle, but I'm having a hard time linking to the large KML on there.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: you could split the kml into pieces with qgis and load each part seperately. Or you could try to provide plain geojson instead of kml

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 2 bottlenecks:

- downloading your 34 MB files
- rendering the polygons as individual SVG shapes.

Analyzing the time spent in each step would give you data about where to work on. E.g. you cpuld console the date before loading your file, in the omnivore ready event, and after adding to the map (assuming you add after the ready event)

As for point 1, you could convert your data to vector tiles / GeoJSON tiles.

As for point 2, you can try first to use a canvas renderer instead of the default SVG one. Solution for point 1 would also greatly help.

Comment: Thanks ghybs and Marcel Gangswitch for your time in answering.  I ended up using ArcGIS online, which sped up the process/rendering of the shapefile significantly.  Surprisingly, the platform was very flexible, and it allowed me to accomplish what I needed to .

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that you can do it by placing a javascript codes referring to a single .kml file, as per below:

```
fetch('lotB.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

            console.log(kml)

            const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)

            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )

      })

fetch('Schematic.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

            console.log(kml)

            const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)

            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )

      })
```

I believe, that we can also put more, than 1 file in `fetch()` command.